# Trouble understanding universal apps, multiple view controllers and xib files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, xib

I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach writing a universal app (iPhone/iPad)...mostly concerning how to handle multiple view controllers and their xib files.

When I start with a window-based app template, Xcode 4 gives me:
- AppDelegate
- iPhone AppDelegate & xib file
- iPad AppDelegate & xib file

I get the idea of the separate xib files, but what I really want to do is add some view controllers with a xib for iPhone & iPad...but I really don't understand where to put what...what to overload, what to connect to what, etc..

I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do (if the view controller can easily be used for both) is create the appropriate files like so.

```
MyViewController.h
MyViewController.m
MyViewController~ipad.xib
MyViewController~iphone.xib
```

Set the `File's Owner` in both the `xib` files to your `UIViewController` subclass and connect up the view + anything else you want connected.

When I init my view controller this is all that's required

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
// OR
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

The Apple docs for [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) state that if you provide a xib with the same name as the view controller it will be loaded. The `~ipad` and `~iphone` ensure that the correct xib is loaded.

Comment: For many cases I use a single `nib` file designed for iPhone, and just make sure it autoresizes properly to iPad size.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. That makes sense, but what happens when I go to connect controls in each xib to the code? Example: I have a slider in each xib that's meant for the same thing, but in different positions, etc.. Do I connect both to the same method? Create separate iPad/iPhone methods?

Comment: Yup just connect the `IBOutlets` up the same in each xib and point any actions back to the same `IBAcion`s